# Spring Integration webservice support

Tags: spring-integration

I went through some documents relating to Spring Integration WebService support.

I currently have a sample webservice , but is not a spring based webservice.

Can I call this webservice from my sample `SpringIntegrtion` application or is there any rule that requires a webservice should be a Spring based WebService?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily call the web service using the `<int-ws:outbound-gateway/>`; the target service does not need to be Spring-based.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the web services in spring itself. You can read [this](http://jpgmr.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/invoking-web-services-with-spring-integration-and-xstream-marshalling/) article for further reference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: link to article is dead. I suggest you either replace it with a copy from way back machine or remove it